# How to create a new variable by merging together input and parameters in nextflow?

Tags: java, groovy, nextflow

I am having the following issue:
I am trying to create new variable within a process that actually would take items from the input section, from the parameter section and create new variables to be used in the script section:
Here is how the process looks like in a meaningful semplification:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process VariantCall {
container 'the_container'

    input:
        val(dna)
        tuple val(meta), path(in_bam), path(in_bam_bai)

    output:
        tuple val(meta), path('out.vcf')

    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/VariantCalling/${meta}/${dna}", mode: 'copy', pattern: '*.vcf'
    
    g_label = "${params.VC}.${dna}.general.label"

    script:
        """
    the_variant_caller \
    -l ${g_label}
    -o out.vcf
        """
```

The params.json looks like this:

```
{
"VC":{
        "nDNA":{
            "general": {
                "label": "",
                "cov_thresh": 0
            }
        "mtDNA":{
            "general": {
                "label": "MT",
                "cov_thresh": 0
            }
}
```

So my goal is to have a g_label variable to feed into the script, that is the composition of the backbone of params.json and the input i am giving (dna).
Then, i run the workflow like this:

```
workflow VariantCall_Module {
    take:
        dna
        in_bam


    main:
        VariantCall(
            dna,
            in_bam

        )

    emit:
        vcf = VariantCall.out
}
```

however, no matter how i phrase g_label i always get:

```
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'TheModule:VariantCalling_nDNA (1)'

Caused by:
  No such variable: g_label -- Check script '././modules/variant-calling-ndna/../variant-call-utils/processes.nf' at line: 21
```

I also tried:

- to have g_label inside the script block
- to have the g_label under `def g_label = "${params.VC}.${dna}.general.label"`
  But same results, with the difference that when i phrase it inside the script block i get as error:
  `No such variable: dna`
  So it looks to me i have a problem with the syntax but also that the dna variable although is in the input (and it's taken without problem in the publishDir statement), it doesn't get passed into a new variable.
  Do you have any ideas?
  cheers!

Comment: The correct place is indeed in the script block, but it's awkward that the `dna` variable is not working. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

The correct place to define the variable is in the [`script`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) block. If you only need a local variable (i.e. it is *not* required in the `output` declaration for example), you can use the `def` keyword like in the example below. Note that with the `-params-file` option, `params.VC` will actually return a `ConfigMap` (a `LinkedHashMap` subclass) object. One way would be to use Groovy's null-safe operator (?.) to get the label value and the elvis operator (?:) to provide a default if it doesn't exist:

```
params.bams = '/path/to/bams/*.bam{,.bai}'


process VariantCall {

    input:
    tuple val(meta), path(bam), path(bai)
    val(dna)

    output:
    tuple val(meta), path('out.vcf')

    script:
    def g_label = params?.VC?.get(dna)?.general?.label ?: "none"

    """
    the_variant_caller \\
        -l "${g_label}" \\
        -o out.vcf
    """
}


workflow {
    
    bams = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.bams, flat: true )

    VariantCall( bams, 'mtDNA' )
}
```

Run using:

```
nextflow run main.nf -params-file params.json
```